# Alloc and init the destinationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@“DoSomething”]) {
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[DoSomethingVC class]]) {
            DoSomethingVC *doVC = (DoSomethingVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
doVC.neededInfo = ...; }
} 
}
```

In the code above, I don't understand why you need the local variable doVC.

If your destinationViewController already exist in the heap, why can't you pass data to it as

```
seque.destinationViewController.neededInfo =...
```

If it doesn't exist in the heap, shouldn't you alloc and initialize it? Is that what this line of code is basically doing?

```
DoSomethingVC *doVC = (DoSomethingVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

You're allocating and instantiating an instance of DoSomethingVC class?
If so, I don't understand how this local variable is going to be kept alive since it's local. Also the sourceVC will also die once the seque is complete.

I just don't understand how the compiler is manipulating the memory behind this process and syncing up the data from this local variable to the destinationViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`segue.destinationViewController` is of type `UIViewController` (even though it is actually a `DoSomethingVC` which has a base type of `UIViewController`) as it stands, so it wont know about your variable `neededInfo` that is why you need to cast it to your `DoDomethingVC`.

It keeps `segue.destinationViewController` as type `UIViewController` to be generic, since it cant really know at compile time what this `destinationViewController` is going to be.

Going on a hunch that your grasp on inheritance is a bit shaky (not trying to be mean) but an analogy would be, if `UIViewController` is say type `Bird` and `DoSomethingVC` is type `Duck`, this `prepareForSegue:` method knows that a `Bird` will be the destinationViewController, but it doesn't know at this point whether its going to be a `Duck` or some other kind of bird, so you have to tell it explicitly what it is going to be (and if you get it wrong its going to do bad things, or crash) also the framework doesnt know what kinds of birds there are (since you are making them), so it cant be factored in for you

Comment: After some further research, I found that the destinationViewController is recreated every time you segue to it. Some I'm assuming `DoSomethingVC *doVC = (DoSomethingVC *)segue.destinationViewController;` is where you're doing this. Still the syntax doesn't really make sense, I don't any alloc init method anywhere in that statement.

Comment: yeah there wont be any alloc in this method, it is done on your behalf already by the storyboard before it gets to this method, and it just passes it as a parameter for you

Comment: The destination view controller is created (alloc/init) by UIKit when it is performing the segue. You don't need to do that part.

Comment: Does the sourceVC have a strong pointer to doVC, therefore keeping it alive even though it's a local variable? I don't understand why doVC is not a property of the sourceVC.

Comment: i think the navigation controller will be in charge of that, this DoSomethingVC will be put into the navigation controllers stack of view controllers thus keeping it alive, although UIKit probably does some other stuff that i dont really know the details of that will keep VC's alive for you while you are transitioning and such (even when not using a navigation controller)

Comment: @user3142893, if the segue is a modal segue, then the source view controller does keep a strong pointer to the destination view controller, in its presentedViewController property.